# Tasker and AutoInput fails to click HTML button by ID field

Tags: android, html, tasker

**TL;DR**

AutoInput does not click HTML buttons with an ID, even though EasySetup sees the ID and suggests it.

**Background**

I am making a HTML based board game timer, and I want to hook up a cheap bluetooth remote control to allow ending the current turn, passing a round etc. The remote sends VolumeUp, which I hope to capture using Tasker and AutoInput and redirect to a Click action on a button on my timer.

**The Problem**

The AutoInput click action times out. If I change it to find the button using the Text of the button and not the ID, then it works. Unfortunately, the 'action-play-pause' button changes the text depending on if the button is a 'Resume Game' button or 'Pause Game' button. (the id stays the same)

**What I've tried so far**

```
SGT PlayPause (this does not work)
  A1: AutoInput Action [ 
    Configuration:Type: Id
    Value: action-play-pause
    Action : Click Timeout (Seconds):1 Structure Output (JSON, etc):On Continue Task After Error:On
  ]
  A2: Flash [ Text:%errmsg Long:Off ] If [ %errmsg Set ]


SGT Primary (this works)
  A1: AutoInput Action [ 
    Configuration:Type: Text
    Value: End Turn
    Action : Click Timeout (Seconds):1 Structure Output (JSON, etc):On Continue Task After Error:On 
  ]
  A2: Flash [ Text:%errmsg Long:Off ] If [ %errmsg Set ]
```

If you want to try this yourself, I've set up a very simple HTML page with these buttons here: https://parakoos.github.io/

All it is is buttons like these:

```
<button id="action-primary" type="button" onclick="alert('Turn Ended')">End Turn</button>
<button id="action-secondary" type="button" onclick="alert('Round Passed')">Pass</button>
<button id="action-play-pause" type="button" onclick="alert('Play Pause')">Play Pause</button>
```

The real strange thing is that the action configurations were set up using the EasySetup mode, where clicking the button correctly identifies the ID field and suggest I use it. Only, it then never actually finds it when I actually trigger the action.

**Alternatives Considered**

If I am unable to make Tasker click the buttons based on ID, is there a way I could get the current text of a button (based on the ID) and then use that in a variable for the click action?

Alternatively, if I could convert the VolumeUp commands to 'Enter' key presses, then I could listen to those in my app and react to them. (I already have that in place in fact.) But I don't know how to simulate Enter key presses using Tasker.

​

Can anyone shed some light on this situation? I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

I received the following from a different forum:

> If the page is being displayed in a browser, this is why. AutoInput
> can't engage with elements within a web browser AutoInput will only
> see the events and activities of the browser itself, not what's
> rendered in it.

I solved the issue in a different way. I made keyboard shortcuts that triggered my desired web app actions, then used Input > Keyboard tasker actions to trigger the keyboard shortcuts.